How can I detect or remove unused TwinCAT libraries in a plc project?
One option is to remove a library, rebuild the project, and check for errors. Is there a better and faster way?
There is an option to remove old unused libraries that are not referenced in the project, by right-clicking on your Plc project and select “Update Project Library Folder”, but this is not what I'm looking for.
